# How do I send a telegram dice?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Below is code for my Discord bot.

```
def dice(bot,update):
    bot.send_dice.message(chat_id = update.message.chat_id)

updater = Updater(API_KEY,use_context=True)
dp = updater.dispatcher

dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('dice',dice))
```

This code produces this error:

> AttributeError: 'Update' object has no attribute 'send_dice'

please help, I have no idea how this works

Comment: It thinks your `bot` is an `Update` instance. Did you transpose the two arguments by accident?

Comment: sorry I have no idea what that means lol

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely due to the fact that you're using the old-style signature `def callback(bot, update)`, while on `python-telegram` with version >=12. The new syntax is `def callback(update, context)`, where `context` is an object that contains the bot instance as `context.bot` and also a bunch of other utility functionailty.

Please see the [transition guide to version 12](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-12.0) (and also the one for [version 13](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-13.0), if applicable) for details.

Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.